# Setting diagnostics json scheme in runtime

Tags: jsonschema, monaco-editor

My use case is that have many kinds of messages, for which I can get json schemes from an http request.

I want to update the schema that’s being validated with when I get the response of the http request.

I’m using angular and making an http request, and when I get the schema, I do the same code like the examples and use setDiagnosticsOptions.

I now realize that this kinda requires the defaults to be set before setting the model, but I cannot do that, because I get the schema in runtime and want to load them without reloading the entire site.

Has anyone encountered this use case and solved this somehow?

Comment: can you please add some code so we can see what you have tried?  please also reference which examples you are working off of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set json defaults after loading the editor.
JSON is validated against the new schema immediately.

Try this code on the [monaco playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) (just paste it and run)

```
var jsonCode = [
    '{',
    '    "p1": "v3",',
    '    "p2": false',
    "}"
].join('\n');
var modelUri = monaco.Uri.parse("a://b/foo.json"); // a made up unique URI for our model
var model = monaco.editor.createModel(jsonCode, "json", modelUri);

var schema1 = {
        uri: "http://myserver/foo-schema.json", // id of the first schema
        fileMatch: [modelUri.toString()], // associate with our model
        schema: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                p1: {
                    enum: ["v1", "v2"]
                }
            }
        }
    }

// configure the JSON language support with schemas and schema associations
monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    validate: true,
    schemas: [schema1]
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    model: model
});

// try commenting out this line to see that v3 is invalid value for a p1 property
schema1.schema.properties.p1.enum = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]

// this reloads schemas, you can add/modify and remove schemas this way
monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    validate: true,
    schemas: [schema1]
});
```

Notice that a new enum value is added after the editor is loaded.
If you comment out a line that changes the schema in runtime the value `v3` will flag as incorrect.